# 'test' is not defined. (no-undef)

Tags: jestjs, eslint

I'm using eslint(JavaScript Standard Style) with jest

lint keeps me warning about jest's functions are not defined.

I tried

```
/* eslint-env jest */
```

It works but, I don't want to use it in every test.js file. so I tried.

.eslintrc (in root directory)

```
{
    "env": {
        "jest": true
      }
}
```

but, doesn't work. any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Is your problem solved?

Comment: @golopot yes! thanks

Comment: Can you post your solution please?

Answer (score 22):

Using:

```
"env": {
    "jest": true
}
```

in the `.eslintrc.json` file, it solved the problem for me.